# React Native Bluetooth Thermal Printer

Tags: react-native, bluetooth, thermal-printer

I'm trying to connect a bluetooth thermal printer on android using react-native-ble-manager, however it doesn't seem to be able to scan for the device.

Scanning from android settings -> bluetooth seems to be fine though.

Anyone have any other examples that I can integrate bluetooth printing on react native?